# generate access key pair for AWS with gossamer3 from python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, subprocess

Is it possible to generate access key pair for AWS with gossamer3 from within a python code?

Running `gossamer3 login` command from terminal creates and stores temporary credentials in `~/.aws/credentials` file.

So I tried to use python `subprocess` package to send `gossamer3 login` command to shell as there is no relevant gossamer3 package for python:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE
con_args = ['~/.local/bin/gossamer3', 'login', '-a', 'profile_name', '--username=user_name', '--password=password']
p = run(
    args=con_args,
    input='\n\n',
    stdout=PIPE,
    encoding='utf-8'
)
```

I see that it runs without errors but the output of this command was not stored in `~/.aws/credentials` file as I expected.

When I tried to retrieve the output from `p.stdout` I got a binary string:

```
'\x1b[0G\x1b[2K\x1b[1;92m? \x1b[0m\x1b[1;99mUsername \x1b[0m\x1b[37m(user_name) \x1b[0m\x1b[?25l\x1b7\x1b[999;999f\x1b[6n\x1b[6n'
```

with type string...

```
type(p.stdout)
<class 'str'>
```

Also tried other decoders and `universal_newlines=True` instead of `encoding='utf-8'` and got the same result. I'm using python version 3.6 (not changeable)

Have to find the generated keys in order to use them farther in my code (to communicate with AWS).
Is there an easier way to do that??

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake.
Need to add `--skip-prompt` to the connection args so it won't prompt for `enter` , make the process to run successfully and save the token in `~/.aws/credentials`:

```
from subprocess import run, PIPE
con_args = ['~/.local/bin/gossamer3', 'login', '-a', 'profile_name', '--username=user_name', '--password=password', '--skip-prompt']
p = run(args=con_args, stdout=PIPE)
```